# Olingo with aws api gateway and lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, odata, aws-api-gateway, olingo

Has anyone implemented odata or olingo using aws api gateway and lambda? I am asking this because I read in a blog which says '$' symboll is not supported by aws api gateway.

Another question I had was how does filtering work with Olingo library? Does it get the entire dataset in memory and iterate over it to filter data?